# If i throws activity during webview loading it crashes

Tags: android, android-activity, webview, fatal-error, sigabrt

I'm creating an app with a webview in which i put a progress bar. I noticed that if i throws an activity during website loading it crashed with this error in LogCat:

```
Fatal signal 6 (SIGABRT) at 0x00004bbf (code=-6), thread 19391
```

So how to avoid this or how to close webview before start an activity?